# Get the text content of individual Elements from an HTMLDocument

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, dom

I have a **jTextPane** that has **HTMLEditorKit** set as the default **editorKit**. Calling **getDocument** on the **jTextPane** returns an **[HTMLDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html)**. I can traverse through this Document, navigating around the elements, but I can't seem to find a way to actually get the text contents of individual elements. I know in the DOM, there is a getTextContents() on each element, but I'm not working with the W3C DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you traverse the document's `ElementIterator`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883413/230513), use the `getStartOffset()` and `getEndOffset()` of each `Element` to calculate the parameters needed to call `getText()`.