# Iterating through JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, document, jeditorpane

In a `JEditorPane`, I want to search for a string, I know that `scrollToReference` won't work, so I want to know how to Iterate through the Pane and find a specified string.

How do I Iterate through a `JEditorPane` to find a specified String in java?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way I can think of is simply to walk through the document.

```
Document document = editor.getDocument();
try {
    String find = //... String to find
    for (int index = 0; index + find.length() < document.getLength(); index++) {
        String match = document.getText(index, find.length());
        if (find.equals(match)) {
            // You found me
        }
    }
} catch (BadLocationException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You could write some routines to "find the next word" based around this concept

You may also find [Highlight a word in JEditorPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448558/highlight-a-word-in-jeditorpane/13449000#13449000) and [Java - Scroll to specific text inside JTextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437865/java-scroll-to-specific-text-inside-jtextarea/13438455#13438455) which both use a similar approach to achieve different things

Comment: You can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448558/highlight-a-word-in-jeditorpane/13449000#13449000) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437865/java-scroll-to-specific-text-inside-jtextarea/13438455#13438455) which use similar techniques

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @Mad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13504827/230513), if your `Document` is an `HTMLDocument`, you can explore it using an `ElementIterator`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883413/230513).